# Expresion regular texto entre comillas dobles que contiene una determinada palabra

Tags: javascript, regex

El lenguaje con el que estoy trabajando es Javascript y mi intención es localizar todas aquellas coincidencias que cumplan un determinado patrón utilizando para ello una expresión regular.

A continuación indico un ejemplo con el texto en el que deseo localizar las coincidencias:

> `<div id="myId"><h3 innerHTML="<span>Título</span>"></h3></div>`

¿Como sería el patrón a construir para extraer todas aquellas coincidencias que contengan cualquier texto seguido de un igual y de un texto entre comillas doble que contenga la palabra Título?

**IMPORTANTE**: *El patrón debe contemplar también cualquier salto de línea, página, tabulación, espaciados, etc que puedan existir dentro del texto encerrado entre comillas dobles.*

Answer (score 1):

La expresión regular que buscas podría ser la siguiente:

```
="((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"
```

Que viene a decir:

- Un signo `=`
- Un caracter comillas `"`
- Un grupo compuesto de cero o más repeticiones de lo siguiente:

  - Una de dos (entre paréntesis y separadas por `|`)

    - Un carácter cualquiera distinto de comillas y de barra `\`
    - Una barra `\` seguida de un carácter cualquiera.
- Una comilla final.

El texto ya sin las comillas exteriores, estaría en el primer grupo de captura del resultado. El grupo interno, ya que sólo era para poder separar las dos opciones del "or" `|`, lo hice un grupo de no-captura poniendo `?:` como primeros caracteres tras el paréntesis.

Lo de la barra es por si dentro de la cadena aparecen comillas "escapadas", es decir, aparece algo como `\"`.

Aqui tienes [una demo](https://regex101.com/r/kgsmcD/1) de que funciona correctamente incluso si la cadena interior tiene retornos de carro, tabuladores, e incluso otros textos entre comillas escapadas.

### Actualización

No había leído bien la especificación, que indica que la cadena a capturar debe contener el texto "Título".

Esto complica un poco la expresión regular, que básicamente se convierte en:

- Un signo igual, seguido de comillas
- Una secuencia de caracteres cualesquiera con tal de que no sean las comillas ni la barra inversa, o bien un carácter escapado (una barra seguida de otro caracter).
- El texto literal `Título` (si también quieres admitir `Titulo`, sin la tilde en la `i`, podemos poner `T[ií]tulo`)
- Otra secuencia de caracteres cualesquiera, como la del segundo punto.
- Comillas (cierre)

Es decir:

```
="((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*T[ií]tulo(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"
```

Como ves incluyo grupos de no captura para las "secuencias de caracteres" del segundo item, y un grupo de captura "global" para todo lo que aparezca dentro de las comillas.

Y [la demo](https://regex101.com/r/kgsmcD/2).

Comment: También encuentra cosas que no son Título, como `<div id="myId">`

Comment: Tienes razón, no había leído correctamente la pregunta. He ampliado la respuesta para este caso

Comment: Mejor :). Aunque fallaría con `<h3 innerHTML="\Libro\Título\Capítulo 1">` De todas formas no queda claro *qué* puede ir dentro de los atributos. Ya de por sí los requisitos son raros

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la solución más sencilla es esta:

```
\w+\s*=\s*"[^"]*\bTítulo\b[^"]*"
```

Tienes una demo aquí: **[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/DxuAGV/3/)**

Sin embargo, dependerá de lo que realmente *permitas* dentro de los atributos. De por sí, tener etiquetas html dentro de un atributo es extraño.

Si dichas etiquetas html además, permitiesen atributos (así pues, atributos dentro de atributos). Se tendría que utilizar una expresión regular más completa como:

```
\w+\s*=\s*"(?:\\(?!Título).|\\|[^"\\])*\bTítulo\b(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"
```

Esto es considerando que los atributos se escapasen con contrabarra `\`. Lo cual tampoco tendría mucho sentido, ya que lo correcto sería escaparlos con `&quot;`

**[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/DxuAGV/4/)** (Si usas esta expresión regular, recuerda a cambiar "Título" en los dos sitios si cambias título por otro texto)

Finalmente, si se pueden dar atributos (sin escapar ) dentro de atributos, problablemente algo así te funcionaría (siempre que el texto relevante esté dentro de la etiqueta, y no en un atributo)

```
\w+\s*=\s*"\s*(?:<\w+[^>]*>\s*)*(?:\\(?!Título).|\\|[^"\\])*\bTítulo\b(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"
```

Tienes la demo aquí: **[Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/DxuAGV/6/)** (Si usas esta expresión regular, recuerda a cambiar "Título" en los dos sitios si cambias título por otro texto)

Answer (score 0):

Mi propuesta es esta:

`[a-zA-Z]+="<([a-z0-9]+)>(\n|\r|\f|\s)*Título(\n|\r|\f|\s)*<\/\1>"`

página,
Esta regex busca cualquier texto seguido de un igual `[a-zA-Z]+=`
y de un texto entre comillas doble que contenga la palabra Título `"<([a-z0-9]+)>Título<\/\1>"`. Entiendo que este texto es una etiqueta HTML. En este caso la primera etiqueta tiene que ser igual a la segunda. También cualquier salto de línea, página, tabulación y espaciados: (\n|\r|\f|\s).

Espero que sea lo que necesites.

[una demo](https://regex101.com/r/YRvNJ0/3/)

Comment: No funciona con `<div id="myId"><h3 innerHTML="Título"></h3></div>`